# d3 force directed graph permanently disables selection

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have finally got my [d3 force directed graph](https://jsfiddle.net/a0xy506g/7/) doing everything I want it to:

- drag on whitespace to pan
- scroll wheel on whitespace to zoom
- drag on node to move node
- shift-drag nodes to create links to nodes (note: in the fiddle, the result window svg must already be focused [click on it] for this to work correctly)
- click nodes to open sidebar (not implemented in the fiddle)
- double-click nodes to expand neighbors (not implemented in the fiddle)
- double-click whitespace to create new node
- mouseover node pops up node info

However, it is also doing something I don't want: **permanently disabling all text selection on the page** by permanently adding a `style='-moz-user-select: none'` property to the page's `<html>` tag (in Firefox) whenever I click on a node or a link. Adding the `-*-user-select: none` style property appears to be standard d3 behavior (e.g. [here](http://bl.ocks.org/rkirsling/5001347)), but d3 typically removes it after the click event fully finishes. This is how it works (in a temporary manner) in my code if you click or drag the background, but when you click a node or link the `style` tag is added permanently.

IMPORTANT: In the fiddle, the style property is added to the IFrame's `<html>` tag, as opposed to the main page's. (i.e., `body` > `form#show-result` > `div#content` > `fieldset.column.right` > `div#result.window.bottom` > `iframe` > `html`)

I believe the problem has something to do with the `d3node.call(d3force.drag)` call on line 364, but if I take it out I cannot drag nodes anymore.

I can solve the problem by simply setting the `<html style=''>` property manually but I'd like to get to the core of the issue, as presumably I'm doing something wrong in d3. I do not understand the event handling behavior of d3 very well.

Comment: From my experiments, commenting out `d3g.call(zoomOn).on("dblclick.zoom", null);` seem to fix the issue. I added a `div` element with some text before `#d3Graph`, and it seems that the bug only occurs (in Chrome) on the second click (not necessarily drag) of a node. My guess is that since `call` binds the zoom to `d3g` it's probably causing strange behaviour because it's typically only called once.

Comment: Are you referring to the `d3g.call()` in the (svg) `mouseup` or (window) `keyup`? (approx. lines 146 and 197, respectively) I tried commenting out all calls to zoomOn (including d3svg calls) except for the initial one, but I still get the same selection problem (see [here](https://jsfiddle.net/a0xy506g/12/)).

Comment: I only commented out the first call in `mouseup`. If you comment them both then dragging the canvas stops working, which would not be good. I think the real issue here is that I just noticed I'm using Chrome. Whoops! It's interesting that I was still managing to reproduce a similar bug, but it seems to be fixed by commenting out the one line. No longer sure about the original problem, though. Personally I'd just try implementing your own `d3.behavior.drag()`, since at the very least the additional flexibility is useful and it may fix your problem.

Comment: Unfortunately commenting out (just the the svg) `mouseup` `d3g.call` doesn't seem to change any behavior in Firefox. I have tried getting into the `d3.behavior.drag()` internals a bit but last time I just gave up since it was confusing and the default behavior seemed to work ok. Guess it merits another look.

Comment: It's not too complicated once you get into it. There are three events, `dragstart`, `drag`, and `dragend`. Here's a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/armarchm/9t2xfqeo/) link which contains very basic drag behavior. One thing of note is that `d3.mouse(this)` is relative to the object that you bind `drag` to, so it's best to use the svg or another stationary element. This example is actually more complicated than need be, all you really need is the start position and offset. The others can be useful at times too which is why I included them.